# Get second to datetime field in sharepoint

Tags: datetime, sharepoint, seconds

I have used a column in datetime format using sharepoint. I want the output to be 1/08/2020 1:43:53pm (along with second values and minutes in all values from 0 to 59). Now am getting only 1/08/2020 1:45pm. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The default date column does not save second value.
[image]
We could use a calculated column to change the format of date,but the second value will be 0.

```
=TEXT(date,"MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS")
```

[image]

I suggest you to create a new date column type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862248(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

http://sharethepunto.blogspot.com/2014/06/how-to-create-custom-field-type.html